# replies or forwards from shared mailbox going into wrong sent items

Tags: exchange-2010

we have many shared mailboxes, most work fine, 1 is giving us a strange problem. 
The one I am struggling to solve is reply/forward behaviour.

Users have full mailbox access and they have the account adding in as an additional account (not additional mailbox).

They can send from the shared account and it goes into the correct sent items.

However, any mail coming into the shared mailbox, when they reply, it sends from the shared account but goes into the users mailbox instead of the shared one.

cached mode is off

Exchange ru11: 2010
Outlook: 365 (2016)

Can anyone shed any light on this?

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing the following:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\<version (15.0 for 2013 and 16.0 for 2016)>\Outlook\Preferences]
"DelegateSentItemsStyle"=dword:00000001
```

Honestly, in my experience, shared mailboxes are too much hassle to support due to things like this.

Comment: They are a hassle but it's entirely necessary that they are able to send and receive from a shared address and I can't see a better way of doing it. I was hoping to avoid using the registry setting if possible as it's working fine for other shared mailboxes, and solving the issue is better than a workaround but if I get nowhere I'll give it a try.