# Replies from shared account on Outlook 2016 not going into its own Sent Items

Tags: outlook, exchange-2013, outlook-2016, shared-mailbox

We're running Outlook 2016 on Exchange Server 2013. We are able to reply to incoming emails to that (shared accounts') email address, but when we do it's being put into the user's account's own Sent Items.

We want the replies to go into the shared account's sent items instead so that the other users sharing the account can reference the information.

The topic at [replies or forwards from shared mailbox going into wrong sent items](https://serverfault.com/questions/841316/replies-or-forwards-from-shared-mailbox-going-into-wrong-sent-items) is pretty much the same issue, although we're using Office 2016 (and Exchange 2013 as stated above).

Also, we need to resolve this without editing everyone's registry.

Is there a way to do this, or am I chasing a dead end? I can't seem to find ANY information on this at all. This SHOULD just be a simple setting, but the solution evades me.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/troubleshoot/user-and-shared-mailboxes/sent-mail-is-not-saved#method-1-configure-the-mailbox-to-save-a-copy-of-the-message-to-the-sent-items-folder-of-the-shared-mailbox-in-exchange-online-or-in-on-premises-exchange-server

Comment: Strangely enough, I have tried this and it did not resolve the issue. :(

Comment: Based on my knowledge, this change does not take effect immediately, you should wait a moment.  And Run Get-mailbox check if the values of MessageCopyForSentAsEnabled and MessageCopyForSendOnBehalfEnabled are configured as true.

Answer (score 0):

It is exactly what joeqwerty has provided, the guidance is very detailed and it may be helpful to you.

In addition, here's a step by step [guidance](https://practical365.com/configuring-mailbox-sent-items-behaviour-delegates-shared-mailboxes/) for your reference as well.